# No puedo configurar imagenes inline

Tags: html, css

Los usuarios seleccionan un método de pago antes de publicar un mensaje (es un foro), luego de que se publica el mensaje, los usuarios pueden ver qué método de pago acepta el OP.

Pero la cosa es que me gustaría que las imágenes de pago se mantuvieran en una **sola  linea**.

Asi lo veo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esto es lo que quiero:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>

<body>

<dl class="pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall pairs--customField" data-field="7">
    <dt><i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar" style="color:orange"></i><span class="forma"> Forma de pago:</span></dt>
    <dd>
        <ol class="listInline listInline--customField" data-field="7">
            <li>
                <div title="Binance" class="Binance2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/mGYD4yt.png" alt="Binance"
                        id="BNCE2" width="27px"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div title="Skrill" class="Skrill1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Q5PhArW.png" alt="Skrill" id="SKRILL" width="30px">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </dd>
</dl>

<style>

body{
   background-color: #1f2535; 
}
.forma{
    color:white;
}
.pairs.pairs--columns.pairs--fixedSmall.pairs--customField {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #1f2535;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  font-size: smaller;
  display: flex;
  border-left: solid 2px #ffa906;
}
</style>
</body>
```

Comment: Modifiqué tu pregunta porque este foro es unicamente para publicaciones en español. No te van a responder en inglés acá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agregue dos selectores CSS para `dd` y para `.listInline`. Tambien agregue un `gap` y un `align-items: center` para `.pairs`. Espero sirva.

```css
body{
   background-color: #1f2535; 
}
.forma{
    color:white;
}
.pairs.pairs--columns.pairs--fixedSmall.pairs--customField {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #1f2535;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  font-size: smaller;
  display: flex;
  border-left: solid 2px #ffa906;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;

}

dd{
margin: 0;
}
.listInline{
display: flex;
list-style: none;
gap: 10px;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items:center;
padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>

<body>

<dl class="pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall pairs--customField" data-field="7">
    <dt><i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar" style="color:orange"></i><span class="forma"> Forma de pago:</span></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul class="listInline listInline--customField" data-field="7">
            <li>
                <div title="Binance" class="Binance2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/mGYD4yt.png" alt="Binance"
                        id="BNCE2" width="27px"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div title="Skrill" class="Skrill1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Q5PhArW.png" alt="Skrill" id="SKRILL" width="30px">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>

</body>
```

Y esta solucion cambia los `align-items` por `baseline` y con un `padding-bottom` se logra algo mas parecido a lo que pediste, pero me gusto mas el primero te mando las dos soluciones jaja

```css
body{
   background-color: #1f2535; 
}
.forma{
    color:white;
}
.pairs.pairs--columns.pairs--fixedSmall.pairs--customField {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #1f2535;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  font-size: smaller;
  display: flex;
  border-left: solid 2px #ffa906;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: baseline;
padding-bottom:10px;

}

dd{
margin: 0;
}
.listInline{
display: flex;
list-style: none;
gap: 10px;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items:baseline;
padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>

<body>

<dl class="pairs pairs--columns pairs--fixedSmall pairs--customField" data-field="7">
    <dt><i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar" style="color:orange"></i><span class="forma"> Forma de pago:</span></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul class="listInline listInline--customField" data-field="7">
            <li>
                <div title="Binance" class="Binance2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/mGYD4yt.png" alt="Binance"
                        id="BNCE2" width="27px"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div title="Skrill" class="Skrill1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Q5PhArW.png" alt="Skrill" id="SKRILL" width="30px">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>

</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Agustín, hay alguna forma de poder mandarte un mensaje privado por stackflow?

Comment: @Chakl22 no uso stackflow pero buscame el linkedin si queres /agustin-guerra/